# Cannot query the date with the grade using Ad Hoc Query

Tags: sql, mariadb, moodle

Currently, I am working on creating Ad Hoc queries to pull from our Moodle database. I am attempting to gather the client name, what course they completed, what grade they received, and when they completed the exam or was graded.

I have discovered the `grade_grades` table in Moodle will allow me to pull all these data values. However, we have a set unenrollment process once the course has been completed. Once, that unenrollment process ends the reporting from `grade_grades` is moved to `grade_grades_history`.

In this query below I am able to pull out all the information I am trying to query except the time. I understand that I am currently not asking the query to pull that value, as when I do so it breaks the query. I am looking for thoughts or information on how I could integrate time to this query as well.

```
SELECT 
   prefix_grade_items.itemname,
   prefix_grade_items.grademax,
   ROUND(prefix_grade_grades_history.finalgrade, 0) AS finalgrade,
   prefix_user.firstname,
   prefix_user.lastname,
   prefix_user.username

FROM prefix_grade_grades_history
 JOIN prefix_user ON prefix_grade_grades_history.userid = prefix_user.id
 JOIN prefix_grade_items ON prefix_grade_grades_history.itemid = prefix_grade_items.id
WHERE (prefix_grade_items.itemname IS NOT NULL)
   AND (prefix_grade_items.itemtype = 'mod' OR prefix_grade_items.itemtype = 'manual')
   AND (prefix_grade_items.itemmodule = 'quiz' OR prefix_grade_items.itemmodule IS NULL)
   AND (prefix_grade_grades_history.timemodified IS NOT NULL)
   AND (prefix_grade_grades_history.finalgrade > 0)
   AND (prefix_user.deleted = 0)
```

Majority of the first part is what I am targeting to pull. The second part is how I would like it delivered as well as additional criteria to sort out NULL data.

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks the query"? What message do you see? What to you observe that is different?

Comment: Also, moodle supports a few different database engines. Is it MySql? Postgresql? Sql Server? For dates and times, especially, how you write this query vary depending on which specific database engine you're actually talking to.

Comment: mariahDB for sql engine, what I mean to break. Is that the query is unable to run, I have attempted trying to pull the ggh.timemodified for when the data is put into grade_grades_history

Comment: But what is the error message? If I add `, prefix_grade_grades_history.timemodified` to the `SELECT` clause and change `prefix` to match what my system uses, the query runs just fine.

Comment: Oh, and a single course could have many `quiz` or `mod` items. If you want **final** grades for a course, you need to do something different entirely.

Comment: Having all the quizzes including multiple attempts is actually preferred in our case. I am going to attempt to make that change you suggested and see what the result is.

Comment: Got that working now doing exactly what you said to do, however now it is show in total seconds, I tried attaching a format unix to break it down into y month day, but that is not working.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ggh.timemodified),'%W %e %M, %Y') AS 'Completed Date',

Comment: AND (ggh.timemodified>= :start_date AND (ggh.timemodified<=:end_date)

Comment: the first is under SELECT, the second is under the WHERE

Comment: Perhaps you need `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

When I last wrote a query to check Moodle final grades, adapting it for your column needs it looked more like this:

```
SELECT c.shortname, 
    gi.grademax,
    round(gg.finalgrade,0) as finalgrade,
    round((gg.finalgrade/case when gg.rawgrademax = 0 then 1 else gg.rawgrademax end)*100,0) as percent_final, 
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname, 
    u.username,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(gg.timemodified,'%W %e %M, %Y') as Date_Completed

FROM prefix_grade_grades_history gg    
INNER JOIN prefix_grade_items gi ON gi.id=gg.itemid and gi.itemtype='course'
INNER JOIN prefix_user u ON u.id=gg.userid    
INNER JOIN prefix_course c on c.id = gi.courseid   

WHERE  gg.finalgrade > 0
    AND gg.timemodified IS NOT NULL
    AND u.deleted = 0
    AND gg.timemodified >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( :start_date )
    AND ggh.timemodified <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( :end_date )
```

Comment: I had something similar in the beginning of this journey, however. We noticed that if we pull from 'grade_grades' only that we were not getting all of our data due to enrollment changing. Whereas if we target 'gghistory' that data never changes so we can get total data. It is working much better now, just need to get epoch time converted into date time.

Comment: This code is using `grade_grades_history`. I just saw no reason to add the `h` to the mnemonic. I did update the code just now to show some date handling. Just be careful with how MariaDB will handle those string conversions.

Comment: trying to use the one you created here, but query did not return any data

Comment: Test the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() conversions separately, until you are sure you are getting correct output there.

Comment: out of the office for the day, will share the results tomorrow, appreciate all the help yet far!